# Quaternion to Euler with some properties

Tags: geometry, rotations, quaternions

I am trying to create a map editor (for GTA SA-MP), and the source game data contains objects with quaternion rotation, whereas I need the editor to output the objects with Euler rotation (XYZ) in degrees, which can be used in SA-MP. I've found this algorithm:

```
double sqx = X*X;
double sqy = Y*Y;
double sqz = Z*Z;
double sqw = W*W;
double unit = sqx + sqy + sqz + sqw;
double test = X*Y + Z*W;
if(test > 0.499*unit)
{
    E_x = 2 * Math.Atan2(X,W)*180/Math.PI;
    E_y = 0;
    E_z = 90;
}else if(test < -0.499*unit)
{
    E_x = -2 * Math.Atan2(X,W)*180/Math.PI;
    E_y = 0;
    E_z = -90;
}else{
    E_x = Math.Atan2(2 * Y*W - 2 * X*Z, sqx - sqy - sqz + sqw)*180/Math.PI;
    E_y = Math.Atan2(2 * X*W - 2 * Y*Z, -sqx + sqy - sqz + sqw)*180/Math.PI;
    E_z = -Math.Asin(2 * test/unit)*180/Math.PI;
}
```

The problem is that it simply doesn't match either the input quaternion format or the output Euler format, like for (0 0 0.71 0.71) it should return (0 0 -90) and not (0 0 90) as it currently does.

To describe the Euler system in the game, I have placed an arrow in the game world and this table shows which directions it points to and which direction it faces (with its one side):

```
 X  Y  Z  points faces

 0  0  0  down   east
90  0  0  north  east
 0 90  0  west   down
 0  0 90  down   north
90 90  0  west   north
 0 90 90  south  down
90  0 90  west   north
90 90 90  south  west
```

To test the quaternion angles, I have placed a vehicle in the game world, which I can get the quaternion angles of. The following table shows the quaternion angles and whe direction the car points to and faces with its top:

```
  W   X   Y   Z  points faces

  1   0   0   0  north  up
 √½   0   0 -√½  west   up
  0   0   0   1  south  up
 √½   0   0  √½  east   up
  0   0   1   0  north  down
  0 -√½   ½   0  west   down
  0  -1   0   0  south  down
  0  √½   ½   0  east   down
  0   0 -√½ -√½  up     north
  ½  -½   ½   ½  up     west
 √½ -√½   0   0  up     south
  ½  -½  -½  -½  up     east
 √½  √½   0   0  down   north
  ½   ½   ½  -½  down   west
  0   0  √½ -√½  down   south
  ½   ½  -½   ½  down   east
```

A vehicle Y axis goes from its front to its rear, X axis is between its sides, and Z axis from its top to the bottom.

While not completely lost at maths, this quaternion stuff still puzzles me, so please be easy on me ☺. Thanks for your help!

**Edit:**

Here are some measured quaternion angles for a given set of Euler angles, which I can set for an object in the game:

```
Euler X Y Z
Quaternion W X Y Z

0, 0, 0
1, 0.000122, -0.000122, -0.000742

0, 0, 45
0.923879, 0.000000, 0.000000, -0.382683

0, 45, 0
0.921593, 0.000000, -0.388156, 0.000000

45, 0, 0
0.922824, -0.385187, 0.002027, -0.004683

0, 45, 45
0.852329, 0.147665, -0.356494, -0.353046

45, 0, 45
0.852672, -0.355673, -0.147325, -0.353186

45, 45, 0
0.859898, -0.349869, -0.353665, -0.114391

45, 45, 45
0.741364, -0.203753, -0.454495, -0.449773
0.728665, -0.190846, -0.466389, -0.463794 (another measure)
```

The measures are probably a bit off, mostly the last ones.

Comment: The exact formula needed depends on exactly which set of [Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) you use -- that is, the order of the rotations. This is almost certainly why you haven't had any answers: most who understand the issue find explaining it tiresome. Flight simulators and car games typically also use different order of axes (due to gimbal lock if nothing else -- quaternions not suffering from such make them so much easier), the former being much more commonly used in examples. Others, myself included, suspect you could do without Euler angles altogether.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Well, I simply have to use them, SA-MP functions don't accept quaternions. I don't seek explanation, simply working code (or formulas) would be sufficient.

Comment: Working code or formulas requires knowing which set of Euler angles is used. Several of them produce the same results with 90 degree rotations, but with differing results for the intervening rotations. If the documentation does not explicitly state the order of the rotations, it can probably be deduced from the orientation of 45 degree rotations ($(0,0,0)$, $(0,0,45)$, $(0,45,0)$, $(45,0,0)$, $(0,45,45)$, $(45,0,45)$, $(45,45,0)$, and $(45,45,45)$). They may be difficult to set up and measure, though.

Comment: @NominalAnimal I've added the measured quaternions to the question.

Comment: Can you re-do the last one (45,45,45)? The quaternion is not a rotation quaternion (it's norm is 0.987 and not 1 as it should be, and it's too much off to be of use), and it is needed to determine the correct order of rotations. Or, you know, you could [ask](http://wiki.sa-mp.com/wiki/Main_Page) those who might know. (And to repeat myself: the formulas you need depend on which order the Euler rotations are done in. I don't know, and cannot tell from the data you're posted thus far, so that's why no formula.)

Comment: @NominalAnimal I've updated the last quaternion with more precise measures (it's norm is now much closer to 1). Thanks for your help so far; I would love to provide more info but I've already searched the wiki and forum of SA-MP, and nobody knows, unfortunately. Even the SA-MP map editor uses incorrect formulas for the objects.

Comment: The $(0,45,45)$ case also looks suspect. Are you sure the corresponding quaternion is $(0.852329, 0.147665, -0.356494, -0.353046)$, and not $(0.852329, -0.147665, -0.356494, -0.353046)$?

Comment: Just to clarify, my answer (you accepted) below indeed does assume second component in the quaternion for the $(0,45,45)$ case was negative, and not positive as in your data above. It does not really matter, though; my point is that Euler angles are ambiguous, and to determine which order of rotations are actually used does need examining many non-90-degree rotation cases -- via test and compare, no less! --, and that makes Euler angles *deceptive*. Many (like SA-MP developers?) think the are "simpler" than versors/unit quaternions, but that is an illusion.

Comment: Finally: One reason questions like this do not get much attention is because there is no "easy" way to determine the order of rotations used. I "cheated" and used Maple, which lets me eyeball-compare the generated rotation matrix, and compare to the ones derived from the unambiguous quaternions, with just a few commands. Even then, much more data -- in particular, those 45-degree rotation combinations (any non-90-degree rotations work, but full set of combinations are needed) -- was needed to actually determine the situation at hand.. That was the hard part. The actual solutions were easy!

Comment: @NominalAnimal I see. Well, your code works perfectly, although I've re-checked that quaternion and got the same result. My intention was to make something like "world to local and vice versa" coordinate and rotation converting function, and the unusual axis order and reversion in GTA was what was making all conversions I've found incorrect. I am aware Euler angles are ambiguous and indeed sometimes unintuitive but, alas, the SA-MP development team decided to use them in almost all of the functions, except the one which gets the rotation of a vehicle - the one I needed to convert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the rotation order is $y x z$, but angles negated for some reason. In other words, the rotation matrix for Euler angles $(\chi,\gamma,\theta)$ used is most likely
$$\mathbf{R}(\chi,\gamma,\theta) = \left[\begin{matrix}
\cos \gamma \cos \theta - \sin \chi \sin \gamma \sin \theta & \cos \gamma \sin \theta + \sin \chi \sin \gamma \cos \theta & -\cos \chi \sin \gamma \\
 -\cos \chi \sin \theta & \cos \chi \cos \theta & \sin \chi \\
\sin \gamma \cos \theta + \sin \chi \cos \gamma \sin \theta & \sin \gamma \sin \theta - \sin \chi \cos \gamma \cos \theta & \cos \chi \cos \gamma
\end{matrix}\right]$$
The rotation matrix corresponding to versor aka unit quaternion $\mathbf{Q} = (w, x, y, z)$ is
$$\mathbf{R}(w,x,y,z) = \left[\begin{matrix}
 1 - 2 (y^2 + z^2) & 2 (x y - z w) & 2 (x z + y w) \\
 2 (x y + z w) & 1 - 2 (x^2 + z^2) & 2 (y z - x w) \\
 2 (x z - y w) & 2 (y z + x w) & 1 - 2 (x^2 + y^2)
\end{matrix}\right]$$
The stated problem is to find the correspondence between the two.

Looking at $\mathbf{R}_{23}$ we can tell that
$$\chi = \arcsin(2 y z - 2 x w)$$
Since $\mathbf{R}_{21}/\mathbf{R}_{22} = -\tan\theta$ if $\mathbf{R}_{22} \ne 0$,
$$\theta = -\left\lbrace\begin{align}
& -\arctan\left(\frac{x y + z w}{1/2 - x^2 - z^2}\right),\; & x^2 + z^2 \ne 1/2 \\
& -\frac{\pi}{2}, \; & x y + z w \ge 0 \\
& \frac{\pi}{2}, \; & x y + z w \lt 0
\end{align}\right.$$
Similarly, $\mathbf{R}_{13}/\mathbf{R}_{33} = -\tan\gamma$ if $\mathbf{R}_{33} \ne 0$,
$$\gamma = \left\lbrace\begin{align}
& -\arctan\left(\frac{x z + y w}{1/2 - x^2 - y^2}\right),\; & x^2 + y^2 \ne 1/2 \\
& -\frac{\pi}{2}, \; & x z + y w \ge 0 \\
& \frac{\pi}{2}, \; & x z + y w \lt 0 \end{align}\right.$$

As a result, I suggest trying the following pseudocode:

```
epsilon = 0.00001
halfpi = 0.5 * 3.14159265358979323846

function euler_angles(w, x, y, z):
    temp = 2*(y*z - x*w)
    if (temp >= 1 - epsilon):
        xa = halfpi
        ya = -atan2(y, w)
        za = -atan2(z, w)
    else if (-temp >= 1 - epsilon):
        xa = -halfpi
        ya = -atan2(y, w)
        za = -atan2(z, w)
    else:
        xa = asin(temp)
        ya = -atan2(x*z + y*w, 0.5 - x*x - y*y) 
        za = -atan2(x*y + z*w, 0.5 - x*x - z*z)

    return (xa, ya, za)
```

which utilizes the [atan2(dy,dx)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation) function available in most programming languages.

(Above pseudocode edited on 2017-09-30, to add the checks for gimbal lock, where `xa = ±0.5 π`. The `epsilon` represents the [machine epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) in this context, and depends on the precision of the variables; typically, it should be a compile-time constant that is easy to modify when porting or running the code on different architectures. The value shown should work well for visualization.)

The corresponding conversion from Euler angles to a quaternion is easy to compute, if one realizes that the three rotations as quaternions are easy to express: $$\begin{align}
&\mathbf{R}_x(\chi) = \left( \cos\frac{\chi}{2} + \sin\frac{\chi}{2} \mathbf{i} \right )\\
&\mathbf{R}_y(\gamma) = \left( \cos\frac{\gamma}{2} + \sin\frac{\gamma}{2} \mathbf{j} \right )\\
&\mathbf{R}_z(\theta) = \left( \cos\frac{\theta}{2} + \sin\frac{\theta}{2} \mathbf{k} \right )\end{align}$$
Their [Hamilton product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Hamilton_product) $\mathbf{Q} = \mathbf{R}_y(\gamma)\mathbf{R}_x(\chi)\mathbf{R}_z(\theta)$ gives the desired quaternion here.

In pseudocode,

```
function quaternion(xa, ya, za):
    cx = cos(-0.5*xa)
    sx = sin(-0.5*xa)
    cy = cos(-0.5*ya)
    sy = sin(-0.5*ya)
    cz = cos(-0.5*za)
    sz = sin(-0.5*za)
    w = cx * cy * cz + sx * sy * sz
    i = cx * sy * sz + sx * cy * cz
    j = cx * sy * cz - sx * cy * sz
    k = cx * cy * sz - sx * sy * cz
    return (w, i, j, k)
```

Remember that both of these functions depend on the rotation order, and that the order of rotations here is $y x z$ with negated angles.

Comment: I've tried your code, but the Y angle computation seems wrong. See [this code](http://pastebin.com/tDX2yPAT). Its sign and value is different.

Comment: @IllidanS4: There was a silly copy-paste error in the pseudocode. Can you retry your tests with the fixed code? (I do not use C#.)

Comment: It works! Thank you; could you please also provide the code for conversion from Euler to quaternion? I think I will also need it in the future.

Comment: @IllidanS4: Sure; added.

Comment: It's been a while, and this works really well. However, I find out that I also need to handle singularities when converting to Euler angles. Can you please also include the test for gimbal lock in the pseudocode?

Comment: @IllidanS4: I added the checks to the pseudocode to match the math shown. If that was not what you meant, please do let me know.

Comment: I think I need something like what is shown [here](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/quaternionToEuler/). They do the check with `x*y+z*w`, so I think I would need a similar check. The current epsilon check also seems to produce incorrect results. [Here](https://pastebin.com/zvDTa3Q0) is the example that behaves incorrectly, both with and without the check.

Comment: @IllidanS4: Have I mentioned Euler angles are evil yet? :) Yes, the initial epsilon checks where incorrect, because the gimbal lock occurs when `xa = ±0.5 π` (and not for `ya` or `za` as I initially wrote in the pseudocode). I only lightly tested this, but it seems to recover all unit quaternions I threw at it correctly (except of course for negation: you can negate all components of a quaternion and it'll still describe the exact same rotation). Could you check if this version works for your corner cases? (And otherwise, too, of course.)

Comment: This works really nicely, thank you. For the 32-bit float I am working with, I have measured the epsilon to about 0.000002. Unfortunately, due to loss of precision, the two quaternions from the example both get caught by the gimbal lock check, but the difference between the results is not that significant to bother me. Thanks again! And yeah, I wouldn't work with Euler angles if I absolutely didn't have to.