# Euler Angle + Distance to XYZ coordinate

Tags: matrices, 3d, rotations

**Background**

I'm familiar with [Euler Angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) and [3d space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-dimensional_space_(mathematics)) systems but I'm having trouble with [Rotation Matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix).

**Scenario**

I've converted my Euler Angle to degrees for `Pitch`, `Roll`, and `Yaw`. Using that vector I'm then moving a distance of 10 from the *center* `(0,0,0)` of my 3d space. I'm not able to get my `PRY` to match my needed `XYZ`.

*note: My xyz space is rotated so Y becomes Z and vice-versa*

**Question**

What rotation matrix do I need to get the following values?

*Format: P, R, Y -> (X, Y, Z)*

- `0, 0, 0` -> `(0, 0, 10)` *directly below center*
- `180, 180, 0` -> `(0, 0, -10)` *directly above center*
- `90, 0, 0` -> `(0, 10, 0)` *directly in front of center*
- `90, 0, 90` -> `(-10, 0, 0)` *directly left of center*

**EDIT** *- Additional Information*

- The Euler Angle / Vector is coming from a mobile device, specifically [CMAttitude](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMAttitude_Class/) which also contains a rotationMatrix property.
- The 3D space I'm working with is controlled by [VES Kiwi](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VES)

*Some 45 degree angles taken from mobile device:*

After crunching these numbers it was a lot more difficult than I thought to get the correct values as they would be in 3D. I made a [short video clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rZEWLIeqrAw) to better demonstrate what is going on.

Comment: The rotation matrix depends on the order the three rotations are applied in, as explained in the Wikipedia article on [Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) you linked to. It is annoying, and you usually need to look at the 45° rotation angles to determine the correct order from data. (I did this for [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1477926/318422) question a few weeks ago.) I believe you're having trouble, because the four orientations you listed are definitely not enough to determine which order of Euler rotations you want.

Comment: @NominalAnimal I added what information I could into an EDIT at the bottom of my original question. I also recorded a short video in hopes that will better communicate the problem I'm having. You're ***awesome*** for lending a helping hand and please let me know if there is any other information I can give that would benefit this question.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're not using the quaternion instead? It'd be much easier: no ambiguities with it. There is a single formula to turn it into a rotation matrix, they're easy to chain and blend, and so on. If you think *quaternion* sounds scary, don't be: it just represents the rotation as $\varphi$ degrees around axis $(n_x,n_y,n_z)$, where the axis is of unit length, $n_x^2 + n_y^2 + n_z^2 = 1$. In CMAttitude, `.w`=$\cos\frac{\varphi}{2}$, `.x`=$n_x\sin\frac{\varphi}{2}$,  `.y`=$n_y\sin\frac{\varphi}{2}$,  `.z`=$n_z\sin\frac{\varphi}{2}$.

Comment: Based on your video, I really see any reason to mess with Euler angles at all. They are **a pain in the butt**. They look simple, but that is just an illusion; versors (unit quaternions used to describe rotations) are so much simpler. Anyway, [Figure 4-1](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/motion_event_basics/motion_event_basics.html) shows the axes used, and [4-2] the rotation directions. However: Based on your video, I do believe you want to **invert** the rotation of the camera. That means...

Comment: ... you could just take the `rotationMatrix`, and multiply its transpose and the vector $(0,0,10)$. If `r` is the matrix, then your $x$ is `10*r.m31`, $y$ is `10*r.m32`, and $z$ is `10*r.m33`.